# NVD3 Styling of SVG

Tags: javascript, css, svg, charts, nvd3.js

Need help finding a way to style the inner `<rect>` of a line chart.

This is the current style
[image: Current style]

and I want this
[image: Future style]

of which is achievable with

```
g.nvd3.nv-wrap.nv-lineChart {
   opacity: 1 !important;
   fill: #f9fafb !important;
}
```

Except, the opacity style is being blocked by what I assume is the default for NVD3.js

[image: Inspect]

How can I remove/change the opacity from 0 of `<rect>`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not to worry, I was thinking more complicated than needed. The fix was simply

```
g.nvd3.nv-wrap.nv-lineChart rect {
   opacity: 1 !important;
}
```